# How to pass a current row value as a parameter to function in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This proc will return many rows.  I need to pass the value of a.assetID from the current row as a parameter to the function fGetAuditDescrConcat.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AuditReportLeaseID]
    @leaseID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        a.assetID as Asset, a.Location, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.auditdate, 101) AS Date, 
        a.qtyaudit AS Qty, 
        c.classname AS Class, a.grade AS Grade, 
        a.serialnumber AS [S/N], 
        a.materialdescription AS Description, a.Notes, 
        (SELECT tf.AD 
         FROM fGetAuditDescrConcat(a.assetId) tf) AS AuditDescription   
    FROM
        audit a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        ORDER_DETAILS od ON a.assetID = od.assetId
    INNER JOIN
        class c ON a.classid = c.classid 
    WHERE
        a.classID = c.classID 
        AND a.leaseID = @leaseID
    ORDER BY
        class, grade, a.materialDescription
END
```

The proc will not compile.  I get an error of "invalid syntax near '.'.
I have confirmed that it is the a.assetID parameter that it is unhappy with.
How can I pass this as the parameter?

UPDATE here is the code for the function

```
  ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fGetAuditDescrConcat]
    (   
        -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @AssetID varchar(64)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE 
    AS
    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT Distinct(T1.AssetID), AD=STUFF((Select N', ' + dbo.audit_descriptionText.audit_text 
 FROM  
dbo.audit_descriptions INNER JOIN
dbo.audit_descriptionValues ON dbo.audit_descriptions.audit_descrID = dbo.audit_descriptionValues.audit_descrID INNER JOIN
dbo.audit as T2 ON dbo.audit_descriptions.assetID = T2.assetID INNER JOIN
dbo.audit_descriptionText ON dbo.audit_descriptionValues.audit_textID = dbo.audit_descriptionText.audit_textID
Where T2.AssetID=T1.AssetID 
order by dbo.audit_descriptionText.audit_text 
FOR XML PATH(N'')), 1, 2, N'')
From dbo.audit_descriptions INNER JOIN dbo.audit_descriptionValues ON dbo.audit_descriptions.audit_descrID = dbo.audit_descriptionValues.audit_descrID INNER JOIN
dbo.audit as T1 ON dbo.audit_descriptions.assetID = t1.assetID INNER JOIN
 dbo.audit_descriptionText ON dbo.audit_descriptionValues.audit_textID = dbo.audit_descriptionText.audit_textID                      
Where T1.AssetID=@AssetID
    )

    GO
```

Comment: Is `fGetAuditDescrConcat` returning a table, or a scalar value?

Comment: It would help if you also provided the code of the `fGetAuditDescrConcat` function.

Comment: YEs - Sorry that is a table function which is why I need to call it with a select in the main query.    See code in edited post.

Comment: Why it is table valued function.does it return more than 1 rows ? Why you need to return Assestid ?If it return always one row then it should be scalar function and Devart is right then.Also you UDF is not well written.You hv use both distinct and order by.There are so many tables in join.

Comment: The function returns one row   Its the proc that will return many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AuditReportLeaseID]
(
    @leaseID INT
)
AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        a.assetID AS Asset,
        a.Location,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), a.auditdate, 101) AS [Date],
        a.qtyaudit AS Qty,
        c.classname AS Class,
        a.Grade AS Grade,
        a.serialnumber AS [S/N],
        a.materialdescription AS [Description],
        a.Notes,
        dbo.fGetAuditDescrConcat(a.assetId) AS AuditDescription
    FROM dbo.[audit] a
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ORDER_DETAILS od ON a.assetID = od.assetId
    JOIN dbo.Class c ON a.classID = c.classID
    WHERE a.leaseID = @leaseID
    ORDER BY
          Class
        , Grade
        , [Description]

END
```

check function after optimization -

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fGetAuditDescrConcat]
(
    @AssetID VARCHAR(64)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @val NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @val =
         STUFF((
            SELECT N', ' + t.audit_text
            FROM dbo.audit_descriptions d
            JOIN dbo.audit_descriptionValues v ON d.audit_descrID = v.audit_descrID
            JOIN dbo.audit T2 ON d.assetID = T2.assetID
            JOIN dbo.audit_descriptionText t ON v.audit_textID = t.audit_textID
            WHERE T2.AssetID = @AssetID
            ORDER BY d.audit_text
            FOR XML PATH (N'')), 1, 2, N'')

    RETURN @val

END
GO
```

Comment: I need to call this with a select because it is a table function and I only need the AD row.  See code I added to the main post

Comment: Thank you @Devart I re-read your answer and this function change solved the issue for me.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AuditReportLeaseID]
    @leaseID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        a.assetID as Asset, 
        a.Location, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.auditdate, 101) AS Date, 
        a.qtyaudit AS Qty, 
        c.classname AS Class, 
        a.grade AS Grade, 
        a.serialnumber AS [S/N], 
        a.materialdescription AS Description, 
        a.Notes, 
        tf.AD AS AuditDescription   
    FROM
        audit a
    OUTER APPLY fGetAuditDescrConcat(a.assetId) tf
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        ORDER_DETAILS od ON a.assetID = od.assetId
    INNER JOIN
        class c ON a.classid = c.classid 
    WHERE
        a.classID = c.classID 
        AND a.leaseID = @leaseID
    ORDER BY
        class, grade, a.materialDescription
END
```

Comment: This one still results in an incorrect syntax on that a.assetID parameter.   This seems like it should work 
Do I need to declare that parameter?

Comment: Can you successfully run `SELECT tf.AD from fGetAuditDescrConcat('someAuditId') tf` what about `SELECT tf.AD from fGetAuditDescrConcat(null) tf`?